# Is there any way to show warnings when Gatsby develop/build?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby, yarnpkg

I am working on a gatsby project using React. I was able to see all the warnings when gatsby develop or gatsby build but the console doesn't show the warnings anymore. I haven't changed any settings related to this. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you.

[console when gatsby build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ItZk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do 'gatsby clean', next run it will show warnings